# scientific plotting software like Excel with more functionality without coding?

Tags: graphs, charts, scientific-computing, plotting

Is there any (popular) software for Mac that generates high quality scientific plots for publications without needs for coding? Specifically, I am looking to generate sub-plots or panels where Excel does not have such functionality.

Seems Plot is one good choice:

https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/20194/plot

Answer (score 1):

[Plotly](https://plot.ly) is a popular online service, with various [pricing](https://plot.ly/products/cloud/) models including some free options, that allows your plots to be generated from:

- Excel Workbooks
- CSV & XML
- A web app
- Python, R, MATLAB & JavaScript APIs
- High-res PNG & JPEG export
- A wide selection of chart types are available